# GTK_Pointer issues in passing structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gtk

I am having issues passing structs (pointers) beyond the original function they were initialized in.

What I have noticed: The further I get from the function I originally initialized the struct in (as I pass the struct from one function to the next as a pointer), I basically start loosing the data (or reference to the data).  When I try printing one of the integers in the struct and it will give me the correct value, then alternates into garbage (possibly mem location??), and then will print out the value again and garbage again randomly.

The program: In the following program I am trying to create a set of 5 Labels in which I can change the text of as I press an up or down button.  The labels are attached to event boxes that, for now, prints the text of the labels onto the terminal.  I am getting segmentation faults when trying to retrieve the text.

The result is I am getting seg faults when I try using the data in the struct (changing the text of labels within the struct, etc.)

```
struct Alpha{
GtkWidget *alphalbl[5]; //array of label widgets
gchar *alpha[38];       //array of characters
gint start;             //start position
gint pos;               //current position
};

void createWindow(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){

struct Alpha alpha;     //Initialization of structure

/* Create window, layout, notebook, menu, etc*/

createList(&alpha, &layer)  //layer is a struct of fixed layouts 

}
```

The struct works in the following function:

```
void createList(gpointer structalpha, gpointer structlayers){

GtkWidget *alphaup, *alphadn;
GtkWidget *alphabox[5];

struct Layers *layer = structlayers;
struct Alpha *alphalist = (struct Alpha *)structalpha;

gchar *alphal[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","<","[]"};

layer->fixedl = gtk_fixed_new();

for (int a = 0; a < 38; a++)                    //Add chararray to struct
    alphalist->alpha[a] = g_strdup(alphal[a]);

alphalist->start = 0;           

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    alphalist->alphalbl[i] = gtk_label_new(alphalist->alpha[i]);
    alphabox[i] = gtk_event_box_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(alphabox[i], 20, 20);
    gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(alphabox[i]), g_strdup_printf("%d",i));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(alphabox[i]), alphalist->alphalbl[i]);
    gtk_widget_set_events(alphabox[i], GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
    //g_signal_connect(alphabox[i], "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(setLetter), (alphalist->alphalbl[i]));    //originally tried sending just the single label
    g_signal_connect(alphabox[i], "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(setLetter), &alphalist);  //<--struct does not send correctly
}

alphaup = gtk_button_new_with_label("^");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(alphaup, 50, 20);
g_signal_connect(alphaup, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(alphaUp), alphalist); //<--struct does not send correctly

alphadn = gtk_button_new_with_label("v");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(alphadn, 50, 20);
g_signal_connect(alphadn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(alphaDown), alphalist); //<--struct does not send correctly

for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(layer->fixedl), alphabox[y], 5, (50 + (y*15)));

}
```

The struct no longer works beyond (in setLetter).  The "->" still finds the variables, but I get segmentation faults when I run the code unless I comment out the gtk_get_text...  I have printed alphalist->start from this function only for it to work intermittently without changining its value.  I have tried adding a '&' to alphalist in the callbacks without success.

```
void setLetter(GtkWidget *alphabox, gpointer alphal){

    struct Alpha *alphalist = alphal;   
    gchar *charnum;

    int num;
    charnum = (gtk_widget_get_name(alphabox));
    num = atoi(charnum);

    g_print(gtk_label_get_text(GTK_LABEL(alphalist->alphalbl[num])));
    g_free(charnum);

}
```

Is the issue that the memory isnt allocated correctly for the struct?  Will calling malloc() solve my problem?  If so where and how?  I've tried adding it in without success.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is strange usage of `gpointer structalpha` and `gpointer alphal` instead of `struct Alpha *alphalist` in function arguments. Gtk uses gponter to hide struct declarations from external access to their members, but you use own declared struct, why you hide it from yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Originally I tried sending the struct as: void createList(struct Alpha *alphalist, struct Layers *layer), but I would get compile errors.  As I am new to gtk, I did not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_signal_connect(alphabox[i], "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(setLetter), &alphalist);  //<--struct does not send correctly`

In `createlist` `alphalist` is *pointer to struct Alpha*. You try to pass a pointer to that, i.e. *pointer to pointer to struct Alpha*. That's a certain mistake, because **this exact value** is allocated on stack and is no longer valid when you return from `createlist`.

---

If the first code block is not `main` but a function, the same problem appears.

Comment: @ Alexander:  Thank you for your reply.  Yes I added the '&' reference to the struct pointer in an attempt to see if the code would work as a last ditch effort.  It has been a while and I am rusty on pointers.  So just to clarify: I would have to call all functions that use the struct from main in order to have the pointers work and point to the correct memory block on the stack? Because main runs for the entire time of the program and so the stack is always there.

Comment: @ Alexander: Yes I understand because this stack disappears when I leave the function createList.  I was trying to point the pointer to the original memory stack, and have the functions modify the original variables in the original memory address(where I initialized the struct).  Is the only way to fix it to put all code into the main and call all functions from there?

Comment: You should study how parameters are passed and how stack works. For example, make functions `foo` and `bar` which accept a pointer to something (say, `int`), and call `bar` from `foo` and `foo` from `main`. In a debugger inspect what is passed and where it's stored.

Comment: E.g. [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/deep-c/363) is a good picture. I __suppose__ you call `createWindow` from main. It means that when `createWindow` returns, all automatically variables (including `alpha`) are no longer valid or reachable.

Comment: Thanks again.  I realize I did not make the struct variable (alphalist) global as to put it on the heap, and then initialize it and send that reference to the other functions.  The fault in my logic was that I was thinking that the method was still active and so the local stack was still intact.  When in fact the method is built and returns to the main loop, and main is running but only waiting for interrupts.

Comment: If I can bother you for one more question.  Is there a way to initialize the struct globally?  Gtk widgets need *widget = gtk_new(); so it is difficult to: struct end -> }alphalist = {*widget = gtk_new(), etc};?   Probably not.  I'll initialize in main and figure out how to send the struct through the callbacks, or most likely rewrite what I have so far.  Thank you once again.

Comment: And yes I'll need a refresher on passing parameters.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You can initialize the struct not in main (and without global variables). For this you must allocate it on heap. You should learn how to allocate memory and what is the difference  between passing parameters by value or by reference.

Comment: Yes in a failed attempt to make the original program work I tried changing the reference/values of the pointers.  I will have to give the entire program a comb through and fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did get a test program to work off of main.  I'll have to modify it slightly to fit what I was doing earlier.  Things to note are that when passing structs in the original program I would get compiler errors unless done with a gpointer.  A function was previously here type error.  Here it works perfectly fine.  I also included a constructor for the struct.  I will see if I can get the original modified and working.  Thanks...

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct Alpha{
     GtkWidget *label[5];
     gchar *num[10];
     gint start;
};

struct Alpha *Alpha_new(void){
     struct Alpha *p = g_malloc(sizeof *p);
}

void Alpha_delete(struct Alpha *p, gpointer data){
    g_free(p);
}

void createWindow(GtkWidget **window, struct Alpha *alpha, gint x, gint y);
void setLabel(struct Alpha *alpha, GtkWidget *button);
void printNum(struct Alpha *alpha);

void main(int argc, char** argv) {

    GtkWidget *window;

    struct Alpha *alpha;
    alpha = Alpha_new();

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    createWindow(&window, alpha, 600, 400);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

}
void createWindow(GtkWidget **window, struct Alpha *alpha, gint x, gint y){

    GtkWidget *fixed, *label, *button;
    gchar *num[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

    *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(*window), x, y);

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();

    label = gtk_label_new("Struct Test");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), label, 280, 50);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("TEST");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 280, 250);

    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        alpha->num[y] = g_strdup(num[y]);

    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        g_print(alpha->num[a]);

    g_print("----");   

    printNum(alpha);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        alpha->label[i] = gtk_label_new(alpha->num[i]);
        gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), (alpha->label[i]), 310, (100 + (15*i)));
    }

    alpha->start = 1;
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(*window), fixed);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(setLabel), alpha);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(*window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(Alpha_delete), alpha);
 }

 void printNum(struct Alpha *alpha){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        g_print(alpha->num[i]);
 }

 void setLabel(struct Alpha *alpha, GtkWidget *button){
     int start = alpha->start;

     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         if(i + start > 9)
             gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(alpha->label[i]), alpha->num[(i + (start-10))]);
        else
             gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(alpha->label[i]), alpha->num[(i + start)]);
    }

    (alpha->start)++;

    if(alpha->start == 10)
        alpha->start = 0;

 }
```